Spring boot configuration properties with arrays
I have a Spring Boot 3.2 application with :
An environment variable
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"basic-auth":{"users":[{"name":"user1","password":"pw1","role":"R1"},{"name":"user2","password":"pw2","role":"R2"}],"patterns":[{"matchers":"/m1/**","role":"R1"},{"matchers":"/m2/**","role":"R2"}]}}

An application.yml containing
application:

  basic-auth:
    users:
     - name: ${basic-auth.users[0].name}
       password: ${basic-auth.users[0].password}
       role: ${basic-auth.users[0].role}
     - name: ${basic-auth.users[1].name}
       password: ${basic-auth.users[1].password}
       role: ${basic-auth.users[1].role}

A class for the properties
    @Component
    @ConfigurationPropertiesScan
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application")
    @Data
    public class ApplicationProperties {
    
        private BasicAuth basicAuth;
    
        @Data
        public static class BasicAuth {
            private List<User> users;
        }
        @Data
        public static class User {
            private String name;
            private String password;
            private String role;
        }
    
    }

And an associated service
    @Service
    public class ApplicationPropertiesService {
    
        private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;
    
        public ApplicationPropertiesService(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
            this.applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
        }
    
        public ApplicationProperties.BasicAuth getBasicAuth() {
            return applicationProperties.getBasicAuth();
        }
    
    }

The controller
@RestController
public class ApplicationController {

    private final ApplicationPropertiesService applicationPropertiesService;

    public ApplicationController(ApplicationPropertiesService applicationPropertiesService) {
        this.applicationPropertiesService = applicationPropertiesService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/basic")
    public void basic() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(applicationPropertiesService.getBasicAuth().getUsers().get(0).getName());
    }

}

It is working fine.
Now I want to simplify a bit with an application.yml like
application:
  
  basic-auth:
    users: ${basic-auth.users}

But is it not working.  The application even won't start.
Failed to bind properties under 'application.basic-auth.users' to java.util.List<com.tuto.properties.ApplicationProperties$User>:

    Property: application.basic-auth.users
    Value: "${basic-auth.users}"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yaml] - 4:12
    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.List<com.tuto.properties.ApplicationProperties$User>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Is there a solution ?
